# Prevent EBUSY error with FileSystem and Node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, queue, append, windows-8.1

I've an async queue with 30 workers, it writes to a single file on Windows 8.1.

My problem is that, being 30 workers, lot of times I get an `EBUSY` error.

This is how I write to the file:

```
fs.appendFile("queue-done.json", JSON.stringify(element) + ",\n", function (err) {
    if (err) { console.error(err); }
    done();
});
```

How can I prevent this error in a clean way?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Get the file handle
- Rename the file
- Append to the renamed file

**References**

- [rename Man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/rename)